# Online365. Does SharePoint sync user photos automatically or all users need to visit Delve page?

Tags: user-profile, picture, ad, exchange-online

As I've understood from this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3185286/information-about-profile-picture-synchronization-in-office-365), SharePoint syncs photos when the user visits "Me.aspx" page (when he logs in it triggers synchronization) Am I right?...

We uploaded few photos to AD, they are visible in users Delve profiles, but not in SharePoint Online. How can I tell SharePoint to sync new photos without asking users to do something?

In on-premise I would use timer jobs or PowerShell to refresh this data, but have no idea what to do in Online.

The only thing I found is [Set-UserPhoto](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218694%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command let

Not sure SharePoint will sync photo if I use it(have no account to test)